# Add and Remove html based on condition

Tags: jquery

I have the following input:

```
<input type="text" name="country" />
```

When a variable `error` **is not null** I will show the message after it:

```
<input type="text" name="country" />
<span class="error">Some error message</span>
```

When the variable `error` **is null** I need to remove the message.

So I have the following, being `element` the *input* tag:

```
if (error != null) {
  var message = element.next("span.error");
  if (message == null)
    element.after("<span class='error'>" + error + "</span>");
  else
    error.text(error);
} else {
  element.next("span.error").remove();
}
```

However, the message is never added when error is not null.

What am I missing? And is there a way to improve my code?

Comment: What sets the value of `error`? You need to do the hiding/showing when that variable is set.

Comment: Is element a Jquery object?

Comment: did you try   element.after('<span class="error">' + error + '</span>');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the comments above, your code should work when revised like this, assuming that element is a jquery object:

```
if (error != null) {
   var message = element.next("span.error");
   if (message.length == 0)
      element.after("<span class='error'>" + error + "</span>");
   else
      message.text(error);
} else {
   element.next("span.error").remove();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An easier way to do this:

```
if (error !== null) {
    $("span.error").text(error).show();        
} else {
    $("span.error").hide();
}
```

In the above example, you would start out with the error span element on the page, but have it hidden.

```
<span class="error" style="display:none"></span>
```

That being said, I can see at least one thing wrong with your code. In this line

```
error.text(error);
```

I believe you meant

```
message.text(error);
```

Also, is the element a variable created from a jquery selector? If it's just a reference to a DOM element and not a jquery object then your code won't work.

Comment: Initially I do not have the span.error in the markup ... So i suppose your code does not work, right?

Comment: I first need to add, in javascript, a span.error after the input ... I will have many inputs so I need to reference the span after

Comment: If the span isn't there initially, the code above won't work. If, as you are saying, you want to dynamically add error elements beside any number of inputs, your method may be better. Another error in your code is that the .next() method returns an array. You are checking it against null, which will never be true. If you check it against length > 0 then I believe that will work.